# Как создать ListView и рулить им в Android?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Есть две переменные:

```
 outputtitle.add(divElement.getText().toString());   
 outputtext.add(divElement1.getText().toString());
```

Как их поместить в один ListView, outputtitle - заголовок, outputtext - текст под заголовком, желательно с картинкой.  
Весь интернет перерыл, ничего не получается.

Попробую уточнить. Например есть код:

```
    public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " выбран", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Так вот, как мне перенести это в обычный Activity?
И ещё, например я создал listview с двумя текстовыми полями (TextView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как мне в них записать информацию, в один получается следующим кодом:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> mainadapter1 = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChReaderActivity.this, R.layout.list, R.id.label, values1));
        listview.setAdapter(mainadapter1);
```

но при попытке добавить текст во второй label ничего не получается.   
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прям таки весь нэт перерыл =)

- [ListView в Android: Кастомизация списков](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/133575/),
- [ListView в Android: Простое использование](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/133569/)

И вообще любая ссылка, по запросу - кастомизация списка андроид.

Comment: Спасибо, но вы меня не совсем поняли! Я же написал: "Весь инетрнет перерыл, ничего не получается.", я искал, в том числе и находил эти статьи, но ничего не заработало. Например в приведённых выше статьях во такой код:    
    `...public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {...`    
Но как мне сделать всё что показано в статьях, он через простой класс Activity. Волнует в общем-то `onListItemClick`.

Comment: все правильно я понял, тебе надо на обычное активити, положить листВью, взять его по айди, написать свой листАдаптер и примерить к листВью, в листАдаптере переопределить метод гетВью и там уже указать свои поля